# How to save an SQL statement's result into a variable?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am on Oracle's DB 12.2.

I want to write a procedure that truncates a table and then saves the result of output into another table, so something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE truncate_my_table_and_save_result
IS
  variable_output varchar;
BEGIN
     TRUNCATE TABLE EMPLOYEES;
     variable_output := SQL%RESULT;
     insert into log_table (result_column) VALUES (variable_output);

   end;
/
```

but of course variable_output :=SQL%RESULT; isn't a valid syntax code, so what should I use instead?

UPDATE: The point here is that I really want to catch an error if it occurs at TRUNCATE (ORA-00054 resource NOWAIT for example).

Answer (score 1):

There is no success flag in SQL or PL/SQL. If it doesn't succeed it throws an exception.

So you could do this (depending obviously on what actual text you want to log)....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE truncate_my_table_and_save_result
IS
  variable_output varchar;
BEGIN

    -- Note we cannot write DDL in PL/SQL. Hence the dynamic SQL.
     execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE EMPLOYEES';

     insert into log_table (result_column) VALUES ('Success!');

exception

  when others then
    /* I really want to catch an error if it occurs at TRUNCATE 
     (ORA-00054 resource NOWAIT for example) */
    insert into log_table (result_column) VALUES (SQLERRM);

end;
/
```

To be honest I think this flow represents bad practice. It swallows the exception, so there's no way for the calling program to know the statement failed. But if we raise an exception the insert will be rolled back, so we need to commit the insert:

```
    …
exception
  when others then
    insert into log_table (result_column) VALUES (SQLERRM);
    commit;
    raise;

end;
/
```

But that's a big clunky. More generally we want out log messages to persist despite what happens with the program which calls them, but without interfering with the actual transaction.

So the minimum acceptable logging implementation would be:

```
create or replace procedure log_message (p_message_text in varchar2) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction:
begin
    insert into log_table (result_column) values (p_message_text);
    commit;
end log_message;
/
```

But really you should consider downloading [Tyler Muth's Logger](https://github.com/tmuth/Logger), which is the closest there is to an Oracle standard logging package.

Comment: I really want to catch an error if it occurs at TRUNCATE (ORA-00054 resource NOWAIT for example), that's why 'Failure' message is not enough for me.

Comment: In which case you want to log the SQL Error Message. I have expanded my answer.

Comment: `if we raise an exception the insert will be rolled back, so we need to commit the insert`, @APC, Is it always true?